# How can I change image of an inflated layout?

Tags: android

Here is my adapter:

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Activity activity = (Activity) mContext;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_initial_activity_viewpager, container, false);


       TextView mTextView  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_initial);
       mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent it = new Intent(activity, PassCodeActivity.class);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(it, ApplicationData.INITIAL_PASSCODE_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            });
```

My inflated layout have a TextView and an ImageView. What I want is when I click the TextView,the **second activity** will be opened and after I finished doing something in **second activity**, I can close it and change image of the ImageView in **first acitivty**. Here is what I did so far:

In the **second activity** I set:

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
setResult(ApplicationData.INITIAL_PASSCODE_RESULT_CODE, intent);
finish();
```

And in the **first activity** I set:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==ApplicationData.INITIAL_PASSCODE_RESULT_CODE){

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_initial_activity_viewpager, null);
            ImageView imageButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_initial_button);
            imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_img_key_setting);
        }
    }
```

But nothing happen.The image is not changed at all and there is no logcat. Please show me how to fix this!

Comment: The code for changing ImageView seems fine. There must be a logical error. Are you sure the if() statement is true ?

Comment: I've just test it and it is seem true.

Comment: You are not updating current layout. You are creating new one.

Comment: @skywall Can you explain more specific, please?

Comment: Oh I get it. Thank you so much skywall :)